# XSL, embed a value-of select within a js function call

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have the following XSL Code (which format's/creates a Table for HTML). The final column in the table has a button which has an onclick event associated with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.0"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<table border="1" id="table1" align="center">
<tr><th>Item Number</th>
<th>Item Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Add</th></tr> 
<xsl:for-each select="/Items/Item">
<tr><td><xsl:value-of select="ItemID"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="ItemName"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="ItemDesc"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="ItemPrice"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="ItemQty"/></td>
<td><button onclick="addtoCart(15001)">Add to Cart</button></td> 
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I'm trying to do is replace the number 15001, with the ItemID... so the code would possibly be something like - but im not sure how it should be constructed.

```
<td><button onclick="addtoCart(<xsl:value-of select="ItemID">)">Add to Cart</button></td>
```

Oh... and here's the javascript code, which it would call...

```
function addtoCart(items)
{
   alert(items);
}
```

As it currently is (passing the value '15001') the code works as expected.
I know I could achieve what im trying to do purely within Javascript (by iterating thru the table to see which button was pressed), but my idea of passing the ItemID within the 'addtoCart' function appears it would be alot cleaner... & well elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) here.

Try this:

```
<button onclick="addtoCart({ItemID})">Add to Cart</button>
```

The curly braces in the attribute indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

Note: You can also use `xsl:attribute` to create attributes, but as you can see, Attribute Value Templates is much less verbose

```
<button>
   <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat('addtoCart(', ItemID, ')')" />
   </xsl:attribute>
   Add to Cart
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim C... it works perfectly to what i want :-)

Comment: The protocol is to mark the answer as accepted (Click on the hollow tick next to the question). That's more effective than saying "thank you" because it increases the answerers' reputation on StackOverflow, which means other users can have increased confidence in answers from that person.